# How to Add Policies to Sails models?

Tags: sails.js, passport.js

I have set policies at the controller level for few controllers and the specific actions in the controllers. But if i have a model with the name `test` and when I call the API  `localhost:<port>/test` it returns the response of the whole data which is there under test.  Basically it does a `test.find()` 
How do I restrict this ? Something like:

`{
   "test":"isAuthenticated"
}`

I'm using passportjs along with sails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to add it in the API level. 
in my routes: 
`'/modelName': { policy: 'isAuthenticated' }`

Comment: This policy is also on controller action for the route defined.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a policies.js inside config folder and specify the policies for the controller there.

```
{
// Apply 'isLoggedIn' to all actions by default
 '*': 'isLoggedIn',
  ProfileController: {
    'foo': 'isAdmin'
  }
}
```

isAdmin.js is a js file inside policies directory. You can get more information [here](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/policies)

Comment: I have successfully added policies to the controller but how do I add policy to a particular model ? For example I have userProfile controller and I have added policies to all the operations in that controller.`'userProfileController' : {
    '*' : ['isAuthenticated']
  }` which is working fine but when say I have a model called userGrades and when I do `localhost:<port>/userGrades` it returns the response I should add a policy to the same.

Comment: You can not add policies to models, you can add policies only to controllers. Models have lifecylcle callbacks, nothing more than that